# Obtener datos de dos modelos no relacionados directamente

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Tengo tres modelos uno se llama "Forms" y el otro "Elementos" , la relación es 1 a N y el tercer modelo se llame "Respuestas" que tiene una relación de 1 a 1 con Elementos.

Un formulario tiene N elementos, pero los elementos solo pertenecen a un formulario. Y las respuestas pertenecen a un elemento.

Un ejemplo seria

- Form 1 ==> elemento 1 y elemento 2
- Respuesta 10 pertenece al elemento 1, respuesta 11 pertenece al elemento 2
- Form 2 ==> elemento 3 , elemento 4 y elemento 5
- Respuesta 12 pertenece al elemento 3, etc...

Los modelos los tengo con las relaciones de esta manera

**Modelo Formulario**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\UsesUuid;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Form extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, UsesUuid;
 
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [''];
 
    public function Elements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Element::class);
    }
}
```

**Modelo Elementos**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\UsesUuid;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Elementos extends Authenticatable
{
 
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [''];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Form');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Respuestas**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\UsesUuid;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Respuestas extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, UsesUuid;
 
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [''];


    public function Elementos()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Elementos');
    }
}
```

El modelo **form** tiene estos campos **form_id**, uuid , name y description
El modelo **Elementos** tienes los campos, form_id, name y title
El modelo **Respuestas** tiene los campos , form_element_id y texto

La relación seria form (id) con Elementos(form_id) 1 a N, y luego de Elementos(id) con Respuestas(id) la relación seria 1 a 1

Ahora deseo obtener todos los registros del modelo **Respuestas** que contengan un **uuid** que esta en form

El ejemplo seria : Form1 , uuid 11000000001 , id 10
Elementos :form_id 10 , title test1 **y** form_id 11 , title test2
Respuestas : elemento_id 1, ....

Mediante eloquent me gustaría obtener las"respuestas" que pertenecen al uuid 11000000001

Para eso estaba intentando algo como esto sin éxito

```
$elementos = FormElementAnswer::all()->formElement()->form()->where('uuid',$uuid)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Partimos del hecho que tus modelos deberían tener las siguientes relaciones declaradas.

Modelo **`Form`**

```
class Form extends Model 
{
    public function elementos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Elemento::class);
    }

    public function respuestas()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Respuesta::class, Elemento::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo **`Elemento`**

```
class Elemento extends Model 
{
    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Form::class);
    }

    public function respuesta()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Respuesta::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo **`Respuesta`**

```
class Respuesta extends Model 
{
    public function elemento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Elemento::class);
    }
}
```

Consideremos que:

El modelo Form y el modelo Respuesta no están directamente vinculados, sino a través del modelo **`Elemento`**; dado eso podemos usar una de las relaciones que nos ofrece Eloquent llamada: [**`hasManyThrough`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

De modo que podamos construir una relación en el Modelo **`Form`** donde indiquemos que: *un form tiene muchas respuestas a través de elemento*.

**La relación**

```
    public function respuestas()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Respuesta::class, Elemento::class);
    }
```

La declaramos en el modelo **`Form`** y pasamos como primer argumento el modelo destino o al que apuntamos y como segundo argumento el modelo intermedio o que nos servirá de puente entre estos 2.

**La consulta**

Entonces podemos indicar que el modelo **`Form`** cargue de forma ambiciosa todas sus relaciones, filtramos por la columna **`uuid`** que le pertenece al modelo previamente mencionado y limitamos a un solo resultado con **`first`**.

```
Form::with('respuestas')->whereUuid($uuid)->first();
```

- Recomiendo por favor leas a detalle la documentación para que si tus modelos no sigan las convenciones entonces agregues los parámetros faltantes en la declaración de la relación antes mencionada.